# How to change window style by sending a message in c#?

Tags: c#, coding-style, window, message

I am trying to change window style of a window in c#.

I have handle of the window. How do I send message to the window to change its window style?

My purpose is to make the window borderless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually need to *change* the style of the existing window, or do you need to *create* it with a given style from the get go? If it's the former (sounds like it, by the rest of your question), then you just override `CreateParams` property on your `Form` (or whatever it is) and change the value of `ClassStyle`, `Style` and `ExStyle` properties on the return value:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
            createParams.Style |= WS_...;
            return createParams;
        }
    }
```

To change style of an existing window, you'll have to use P/Invoke to call `GetWindowLong` to retrieve the current value of `GWL_STYLE` (or `GWL_EXSTYLE`, whichever you need) for the window, flip the bits as needed, and call `SetWindowLong` to set it back. You can find P/Invoke signatures for both functions, as well as an example that uses them with `GWL_EXSTYLE`, [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowLong.html).

Comment: I need to change the style of the existing window.

Comment: Updated answer to cover that case.